# Problem installing Mxnet using pip on Windows

Tags: python, numpy, pip, mxnet

I am trying to install mxnet on my windows but receiving below error which seems is related to numpy. I tried to manually uninstall numpy or install other versions of mxnet but it did not work.

```
    Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
```

the whole error is provided here:

```
C:\Users\salma>pip install mxnet
Collecting mxnet
  Using cached mxnet-1.7.0.post2-py2.py3-none-win_amd64.whl (33.1 MB)
Collecting numpy<1.17.0,>=1.8.2
  Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: graphviz<0.9.0,>=0.8.1 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from mxnet) (0.8.4)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from mxnet) (2.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.19.0,>=2.18.4->mxnet) (2020.12.5)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: numpy, mxnet
  Attempting uninstall: numpy
    Found existing installation: numpy 1.20.2
    Uninstalling numpy-1.20.2:
      Successfully uninstalled numpy-1.20.2
    Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\salma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th72adgn\\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\salma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th72adgn\\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yvm59o3x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\numpy'
         cwd: C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\
    Complete output (273 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)


    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
      return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\salma\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-th72adgn\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      self.calc_info()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of numpy
  Moving to c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy-1.20.2.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~umpy-1.20.2.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\
   from C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~umpy
  Moving to c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\scripts\f2py.exe
   from C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-0wm0q7pe\f2py.exe
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\salma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th72adgn\\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\salma\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-th72adgn\\numpy_5086d498c04c4df58df468cf33c58ba6\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\salma\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-yvm59o3x\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\salma\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: MXNet wants to install an old version of `numpy` which wasn't built for Python 3.9. Either use Python 3.7, or install/configure C and Fortran compilers among with other stuff for compiling `numpy` on Windows, see [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/building.html) for build instructions.

Comment: @hoefling thanks. that hepled a lot. I created an environment using python 3.7.